# Find $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{R}$ so that the $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)$ exists.

Tags: calculus, limits

Find $a, b, c, d\in\mathbb{R}$ so that the limit: $$\lim_{x\to1} f(x)$$ exists, when:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{ax^{3}-(b+c)x-(a+d)}{(x-1)^{2}} & x<1 \\
\frac{bx^{2}-ax+(b+d)}{(x-1)^{2}} & x>1
\end{cases}
$$

I'm sure that I have to use the fact that in order for the limit :$$\lim_{x\to1} f(x)$$ to exist, this must be true:

$$\lim_{x\to1^{-}} f(x)=\lim_{x\to1^{+}} f(x)$$
The problem I have with this exercise is that I can't seem to find a way to simplify the fractions in: $$\lim_{x\to1^{-}} f(x)$$ or: $$\lim_{x\to1^{+}} f(x)$$ so that I don't get infinity as a result. Meaning I can't progress into finding the values of $a, b, c, d$

Any help or hints are welcomed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It doesn't actually seems possible for this limit to exist with the given conditions. The exercise itself seems to be erroneous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one-sided limits can only exist if
$$ax^3-(b+c)x-(a+d)=A(x-1)^2(x-B)$$
and
$$bx^2-ax+(b+d)=C(x-1)^2$$
for some $A,B,C$. Can you see why? Can you continue?

**EDIT:** As [Peter Foreman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/631494/peter-foreman) pointed it out in the comments, there is no $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the limit exist..

Comment: I don't think it's actually possible for the limit to exist. I keep getting contradictory equalities. Can you check to see if I'm just being stupid.

Comment: @PeterForeman Yes, I'm going to grab a paper and calculate it.

Comment: @PeterForeman I tried it several times, and I'm getting contradictory equalities as well, so I think the problem is in the exercise.

Comment: Phew I'm not crazy! It may be helpful to note this in your answer.

Comment: @PeterForeman I did it, thanks. Honestly, I didn't even consider the non-existence of the solution.

Comment: @Botond I can see why what you write is correct however i dont get get why in the first equality the second part is A(x - 1)^2*(x - B) but in the second its C(x - 1)^2.How are the second parts of the equalities created? I get the A(x - 1)^2  since we need it in order to simplify the fraction.But what about the rest?

Comment: @dimpap The first polynomial is $ax^3-(b+c)x-(a+d)$, so it's a degree $3$ polynomial. So it can be written as $a(x-x_1)(x-x_2)(x-x_3)$, where $x_1,x_2,x_3$ are the roots of the polynomial. $2$ of the roots must be $1$, so we are left with $ax^3-(b+c)x-(a+d)=a(x-1)(x-1)(x-x_3)=a(x-1)^2(x-x_3)$. On the other hand, the degree of $bx^2-ax+(b+d)$ is $2$, so it must have the form $b(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=b(x-1)(x-1)=b(x-1)^2$. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Botond Yes thanks a lot for the clarification and the  quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

The limit$$\lim_{x\to1^-}\frac{ax^3-(b+c)x-(a+d)}{(x-1)^2}\tag1$$exists (in $\mathbb R$) if and only if$$(x-1)^2\mid ax^3-(b+c)x-(a+d).\tag2$$For this to happen, you need to have$$x-1\mid ax^3-(b+c)x-(a+d).\tag3$$But\begin{align}x-1\mid ax^3-(b+c)x-(a+d)&\iff a\times1^3-(b+c)\times1-(a+d)=0\\&\iff d=-b-c.\end{align}So, assume that $d=-b-c$. Now, you know that $(3)$ holds. In fact,\begin{align}\frac{ax^3-(b+c)x-(a+d)}{x-1}&=\frac{ax^3-(b+c)x-(a-b-c)}{x-1}\\&=ax^2+ax+a-b-c.\end{align}And we have $(2)$ if and only if $a\times1^2+a\times1+a-b-c=0$, which is equivalent to $c=3a-b$.

Now, you know that the limit $(1)$ exists if and only if $d=-b-c$ and $c=3a-b$. Now, do the same thing with the limit$$\lim_{x\to1^+}\frac{bx^2-ax+b+d}{(x-1)^2}.$$